# Problem installing printer Canon Pixima 5150

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

The system discover the device. But i can not print.

But i can not install the drivers . 
I already download them from the official Canon web page. 
when i execute  ./install this is the output.

```
==================================================
```

Canon Inkjet Printer Driver Ver.3.40-1 for Linux
Copyright CANON INC. 2001-2010
All Rights Reserved.

==================================================
An error occurred. The package management system cannot be identified.

i also try to add manual the PPD file but i get other error :

```
Idle - File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstocanonij" not available: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and use these lines:

1. Check if you have **gdebi** installed:

   which gdebi

if **not**, then:

```
sudo apt install gdebi-core gdebi
```

2. Add the **Ubuntu Trusty Extra Packages Repo**

   sudo su

If Got “User is Not in Sudoers file” then Look: [Solution](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2012/03/05/linuxsudoerrorisnotinthesudoersfile/)

```
echo 'deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe' 
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extra.list

$ apt update
```

3. Install **packages**:

   sudo apt install libpng12-0 libpango1.0-0

..
4. Extract the **Canon package** in the **/tmp** directory
[image]

5. Install the package with

   cd /tmp/cnijfilter*deb/packages

*if 32-bit system:*

```
sudo gdebi ./*i386.deb
```

*if 64-bit system*

```
sudo gdebi ./*amd64.deb
```

6. Installing **Canon MG5150 Printer Driver**

   cd /tmp/cnijfilter*deb

   sudo ./install.sh

You can be asked to connect or turn on the printer:
[image]

7. Finally, go to **settings**, to **Add a Printer**

*It should be recognized and installed:*

[image]

Comment: Hello Grigor, thanks for the instruction, 
Its was rely helpful . 
I fallow all the steps expect:
sudo apt install libpng12-0 libpango1.0-0

because i get an error: 

Package libpng12-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source


Now i moved forward :) one step. 
Now i see the printer, i start the test page, there is no errors, but nothing happened. It didnt print :/ 
Any clues ?

Comment: try $ sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart  and then $ sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p MG5100 -m canonmg5100.ppd -v cnijusb:/dev/usb/lp0 -E  and last line - $ sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -d MG5100

Comment: unfortunately something goes wrong :/

'~$ sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p MG5100 -m canonmg5100.ppd -v cnijusb:/dev/usb/lp0 -E
[sudo] password:
lpadmin: Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS.
lpadmin: Unable to copy PPD file.'

Answer (score 0):

In search of a solution for Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS I stumbled upon another answer to this question. While it may still apply, I had problems to install required older library versions alongside newer versions.

On a [French Ubuntu forum thread](https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2051706) I found the solution to add a certain PPA. Here are the detailed steps which led to a successful print:

1. Verify, that your printer is supported. The MG5150 is supported according to [this French list](https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/liste_imprimantes_canon).
2. The PPA is maintained on [Launchpad here](https://launchpad.net/%7Ethierry-f/+archive/ubuntu/fork-michael-gruz). It tells you to add the PPA as follows. Keep in mind that you must trust the PPA owner with what they offer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
sudo apt-get update
```

3. Once that is done, you can check the list in step (1) again to see, which packages you need to install now. For the MG5150 this was required:

```
sudo apt-get install cnijfilter-mg5100 scangearmp-mg5100
```

4. After that, the printer (connected via USB) got automatically detected by the system and opening the printer settings allowed me to print a test page.